# BaseException in Angular2 with ES6 and Webpack

Tags: exception, ecmascript-6, webpack, angular

When I use `Angular2`, `Webpack` and `ES6`, all runs well but the console show the above error, I don't know what's wrong with it.

#### Log

```
BaseException {
    message: "Token must be defined!", 
    _originalException: undefined, 
    _originalStack: undefined, 
    _context: undefined, 
    stack: "Error: Token must be defined!
}
at new BaseExcep… at http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js:42471:32"
```

#### Preview

[image]

Code can be found in https://github.com/wxyyxc1992/angular2-es6-webpack-quickstart

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Please post some sample code